# Using a native Win7 batch to find a users profile registry entry and delete it?

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, registry, user-profile

I'm creating a batch where part of it locates the registry entries tied in with the user profile and removes them. The other part simply renames the profile folder under C:\Users so the My Docs and Desktop data can be copied back over to the new one when the user logs in. Renaming saves time by not having to copy the entire users profile to another location - which sometimes can be 30-40GB in size. This is what I've got. It's meant to be ran while logged in as a local admin:

```
@echo off
MODE 75,30

:Declarations
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set date=%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%%
color 0a

echo 1. - Recreate a Windows User Profile
::Completely removes a User Profile, Logs off, then Restores Data(this will be coded later)

echo.0. - Exits

set /p input=Choose a number and press enter: 
if %input%==1 goto :1
if %input%==0 goto :0

:1
cls
@echo off
TITLE Removing Windows Profile

set /p EUID= Enter the users EUID: 

rename "C:\Users\%EUID%" "C:\Users\%EUID%.%DATE%"

cls

echo Complete. User Profile removed.

pause

shutdown -l

0:
exit
```

So I need to somehow find the registry entries as well (probably right after it renames the user profile) using the provided username, then delete them. I know the registry entries aren't exactly titled by the users login name, so your help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks folks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you would search for a registry key using batch, (maybe the [`reg query`](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/regsearch.php) command will help) but you can use the [`reg delete`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc742145.aspx) command to delete registry keys and folders.

Answer (score 0):

I butchered the below from [here](http://mstoneblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/08/user-profile-cleaning-script-for-windows-7/) into what you need. I use the source heavily modified for my own code. This is a bit more robust that I think you need but it should work. It Queries the registry for every profile on the computer and if it finds the one you listed, then it renames the profile and removes the registry entry. I would replace the line in your code that does the actual renaming with this. I would also move the `:0 EXIT` to above the `:1` Most of the extra stuff is for dealing with spaces in paths and user names. I left in the `:SKIP` so you have an idea that it is skipping a profile, you could just replace `GOTO :SKIP` with `GOTO :EOF`

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('reg query "hklm\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\profilelist"^|find /i "s-1-5-21"') DO CALL :REGCHECK "%%a"
GOTO END

:REGCHECK
set SPACECHECK=
FOR /f "tokens=3,4" %%b in ('reg query %1 /v ProfileImagePath') DO SET USERREGPATH=%%b %%c
FOR /f "tokens=2" %%d in ('echo %USERREGPATH%') DO SET SPACECHECK=%%d
IF ["%SPACECHECK%"]==[""] GOTO REGCHECK2
GOTO USERCHECK

:REGCHECK2
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('reg query %1 /v ProfileImagePath') DO SET USERREGPATH=%%g
GOTO USERCHECK

:USERCHECK
FOR /f "tokens=3 delims=\" %%e in ('echo %USERREGPATH%') DO SET USERREG=%%e
FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%f IN ('echo %USERREG%') DO SET USERREGPARSE=%%f
ECHO %EUID%|find /I "%USERREGPARSE%" > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL=0 GOTO CLEAN
IF ERRORLEVEL=1 GOTO SKIP

:SKIP
GOTO :EOF

:CLEAN
rename "C:\Users\%EUID%" "C:\Users\%EUID%.%DATE%"
reg delete %1 /f
GOTO :END

:END
Pause

:EOF
```

So with the changes I made It would look like the below.

```
@echo off
MODE 75,30

:Declarations
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set date=%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%%
color 0a

echo 1. - Recreate a Windows User Profile
::Completely removes a User Profile, Logs off, then Restores Data(this will be coded later)

echo.0. - Exits

set /p input=Choose a number and press enter: 
if %input%==1 goto :1
if %input%==0 goto :0

:0
exit

:1
cls
@echo off
TITLE Removing Windows Profile

set /p EUID= Enter the users EUID: 

FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('reg query "hklm\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\profilelist"^|find /i "s-1-5-21"') DO CALL :REGCHECK "%%a"
GOTO END

:REGCHECK
set SPACECHECK=
FOR /f "tokens=3,4" %%b in ('reg query %1 /v ProfileImagePath') DO SET USERREGPATH=%%b %%c
FOR /f "tokens=2" %%d in ('echo %USERREGPATH%') DO SET SPACECHECK=%%d
IF ["%SPACECHECK%"]==[""] GOTO REGCHECK2
GOTO USERCHECK

:REGCHECK2
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('reg query %1 /v ProfileImagePath') DO SET USERREGPATH=%%g
GOTO USERCHECK

:USERCHECK
FOR /f "tokens=3 delims=\" %%e in ('echo %USERREGPATH%') DO SET USERREG=%%e
FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%f IN ('echo %USERREG%') DO SET USERREGPARSE=%%f
ECHO %EUID%|find /I "%USERREGPARSE%" > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL=0 GOTO CLEAN
IF ERRORLEVEL=1 GOTO SKIP

:SKIP
GOTO :EOF

:CLEAN
rename "C:\Users\%EUID%" "C:\Users\%EUID%.%DATE%"
reg delete %1 /f
GOTO :END

:END
cls

echo Complete. User Profile removed.

pause

shutdown -l

:EOF
```

Are you the only one using this script? if so I should work fine, if not, you will really want to clean up the user input parts and possibly use basic vbs message boxes to make them more durable.